# ODE with cross products

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cross-product

I've been working on a project about the dynamics of spins and I've encountered the following system of ODEs which I'm unable to solve:
$$\frac{dS_1}{dt} = S_1 \times S_2 + \gamma S_1 \times (S_1 \times S_2)$$
$$\frac{dS_2}{dt} = S_2 \times S_1 + \gamma S_2 \times (S_2 \times S_1).$$

What I did was to set $u = S_1 \times S_2,$ then differentiate to get $\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{dS_1}{dt} \times S_2 + S_1 \times \frac{dS_2}{dt}.$ Making the substitutions and after some calculations I arrived at $$\frac{du}{dt} = u \times (S_1 + S_2),$$ and I'm stuck at this point. I forgot to mention that $S = (S_x, S_y, S_z)$ with $\|S\| = 1$ and $\gamma >0.$

Any help to find a solution would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is this system Hamiltonian? Because you already have two integrals of motion: $S_1^2$ and $S_2^2$.

Comment: What I'm looking at is the interaction part of the Hamiltonian, i.e. $H = S_1 \cdot S_2 + ... + S_{N-1} \cdot S_N.$ I'm also using the LL equations for the dynamics $dS_i/dt = S_i \times dH/dS_i + \gamma S_i \times (S_1 \times dH/dS_i).$ The system of ODEs is obtained by considering just the term $S_1 \cdot S_2$ of $H.$